# What kind of tests should I write in my case?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, integration

I'm kinda new to unit tests, functional tests, etc.

I'm a little confused as to the best approach for my case:

My service does this :

1. connect to a remote server through SFTP
2. copy some XML files locally
3. parse those files
4. save the parsed data in the database

My service is working fine but my question is: How can I test this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on testing the most risky elements of your code. By "risky elements" I mean things that are likely to be implemented incorrectly or incompletely, or that may break later when you make other changes.

One easy way to tell what you should be testing are the parts where you hit "refresh" or "compile" a lot just to see what would happen and whether you were done. For instance, you mentioned your system parses XML files: you might have wanted a wide range of input XML files to make sure they all worked, but if some perfect person handed you the XML parsing code and said "this is guaranteed to work" you probably wouldn't have exercised or explored by hand. *Automated testing allows you to be that perfect person*, or at least to know when your code is very likely to work. Furthermore, if you discover a case where that system *wasn't* working, it allows you to write a test to determine when your system does work for that case, and to ensure that your changes don't cause the system to fail for any of the previous tests you've written.

To that point, you will be the best expert on which pieces of your system are the most risky, so you can best write tests to mitigate that risk. You may also need to restructure your code to be flexible enough to test, which might include making fields and methods visible or allowing for a substitute database connection in your database handling code; this is normal and valuable, if it enables your system to be more testable.

---

Unit tests are good for small and self-contained systems, which means that they aren't necessarily good for all of the pieces in your stack:

> 1. connect to a remote server through SFTP

This part might be difficult to unit test, because you don't necessarily want your test to fail if your computer is offline or the SFTP server is down. It may be a good idea to write a *functional test* or *integration test* to ensure that your system continues to work with the SFTP server you want.

If you want to check that your system is interpreting your configuration correctly to *issue the right request to the right SFTP server*, that might be a good unit to test, but will only guarantee that you are making the right request, not that it gives you the right response or behavior. This might be a good case for a [mock framework](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) (mocking your FTP calls), but that suffers from the same problem: You can verify that you are making the expected request, but not that the right response comes out of it.

> 2. copy some XML files locally

Working with the file system can be difficult in unit tests, because you need to make sure that you set up your files in a temporary directory or other predictable place that will not be affected by real data or previous tests. However, this can be done: You can create an example XML file, run your copying code, and verify that the result is in the expected place.

Once again, you could use mocks or stubs to verify that you're making the right calls to the filesystem, which might be more predictable than using the real filesystem but only guarantees that you're making the expected calls, not that you're getting the right results.

> 3. parse those files

This is a very easy case for unit testing. Prepare or download some example files, run them through your parser, and make sure that the output is what you expect.

> 4. save the parsed data in database

This part is also easy to test, if laborious: You can take example data that you've parsed, send it to your system, and then read the database to ensure that the pieces are in there as you expect. The difficulty here may be in ensuring that your database is set up similarly to production but without using the real production database; you might want to use an in-memory database.

Again, you have the choice to simply check that the database commands are accurate: You may decide it is sufficient to ensure you're using the right query with the right parameters. However, using a real database engine will give you a more thorough test, ensuring that the command is successful, that it passes any database validation rules about required fields or formats, and that it doesn't truncate or drop characters or number precision.

An integration test could ensure that, for a given XML file, it correctly makes its way all the way through to the database; however, a test like that will likely be slower, and if it fails you may have to do more work to figure out which unit was failing. Consequently, you should probably think about comprehensive unit tests as soon as possible, and focus on integration and end-to-end tests later.

**See also:** [Are (database) integration tests bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/301479/71634), a related question I answered on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange